# Emacs org mode shortcut to create code block

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings

When using org mode, how can I map a specific keybinding (ex. `C-c s`) to create an org code snippet that looks like this:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python

#+END_SRC
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always write a function that inserts a string and then bind it to a key:

```el
(defun insert-python-src-block ()
   (interactive)
   (insert "#+BEGIN_SRC python\n\n#+END_SRC"))

(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c s") #'insert-python-src-block)
```

But key bindings are scarce commodities; they also tend to be hard to remember when they proliferate. So most people prefer a templating mechanism for this. Org mode provides one based on the variable `org-structure-template-alists`. You get extensibility, but you don't get to choose an arbitrary keybinding for it.

Here's how that works - you add this to your init file:

```el
(with-eval-after-load 'org
   (add-to-list 'org-structure-template-alist '("p" . "src python")))
```

Then you invoke *any* of the templates with `C-c C-,`  (bound to `org-insert-structure-template`) which gives you a menu of possibilities: choosing `p` inserts the new template you added.

For details, do `C-h v org-structure-template-alist RET` to read the doc string of the variable, do `C-h f org-insert-structure-template` to read the doc string of the function, and read the [Structure templates](https://orgmode.org/manual/Structure-Templates.html#Structure-Templates) section of the manual either online, or locally with `C-h i g(org)Structure templates RET` which also describes the backward-compatible `org-tempo` based method as well.

There are other templating mechanisms: `yasnippets` seems to be the most popular, but I don't know enough about it to describe it here.